# Есть ли в Yii достойный CRUD генератор

Tags: crud, yii, codeigniter

В связи с предрекающей всеми спецами мира программирование гибели моего очень  любимого codeignitera    решил ускорить переход на YII.И Вот такой вопрос есть ли у данного фреймворка такою супер CRUD генератор как у CI http://www.grocerycrud.com.
Знаю что там есть встроенный но.. хотя бы на 50% есть такое же продвинутый как у CI.

Comment: Ждёте ответа от пользователей Yii об функционале CI, так описали бы что конкретно вма надо, иначе ответить на ваш вопрос смогут только те, кто знаком и с первыми, и со вторым, а таких определенно меньше, чем знакомых только с Yii.

Answer (score 6):

я если честно поражен, что человек восхваляющий CI не может найти документацию по Yii

У Yii есть [GII](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.gii) он то и генерит код.

ссылка есть читай.

Comment: Если честно меня поражает человек которые не может ответить на вопрос нормально, я прошел ся по документации и не могу найти хотя бы на 10% такой генератор.

Comment: Ну если ты и с подсказками не можешь по ссылкам пройти и прочитать.

То это твоя нелегкая учесть.

Или по ссылке тебе открывается порно?

Comment: Я хорошо знаком с gii но это совсем не то.

Comment: Нет, другого нет.